# Can entries from multiple org-mode files with date trees be consolidated into a single timeline?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

For example,  is there a way to combine entries from a work diary.org, workout.org, and personal.org file to produce an entry like:

```
* 2017
** 2017-01-30 Monday
*** onboarded new employee
*** reviewed proposals
*** ran 3 miles (24 min.)
*** parent-teacher conference
```

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Read the question and answer in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208842/how-to-parse-org-mode-by-org-element-elegantly?answertab=votes#tab-top) . This not the answer to your question - but the direction!

Comment: Produce an entry like this where? In the agenda? In a search tree? In another file?